# How to get selected radio button choice in django form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, django-forms

I've a form

```
class ScoreUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    answer_id = forms.IntegerField()
    given_score = forms.FloatField()
    CHOICES = [('calculated_score', 'Calculated Score'),
               ('given_score', 'Given Score')]

    final_score = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Here is my template

```
 <form action="/teachers/questions/{{ answer.question.id }}/score" method="post">
    {{ form.given_score }}
    {{ form.final_score }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

here is my view

```
def score(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ScoreUpdateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                given_score = form.cleaned_data['given_score']
                final_score = form.cleaned_data['final_score']
```

I can get given_score value but not the final_score. I want to get the value of the selected choice in my view after the post.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
 final_score = form.cleaned_data['final_score']
 final_score = dict(form.fields['final_score'].choices)[final_score]
```

Comment: It isn't returning any value